# Avoid Casting when Consumer Function takes a Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, base-class

How can do the below commented line please i.e. "//How to do this without casting?". What I mean is how to do it by changing my design, I know I can't do it this way. Some ugly ways I thought about:

1. Casting (maybe not ugly for some), is `std::static_pointer_cast` fast? Is it compile time or run time operation, also can I do it without a lot of ifs i.e. please remember the comment: "//I can't be a template and there are a lot of me".
2. Implement all member function needed in `BaseConsumable` with a throw, this is ugly, also it does increase the memory allocated to the `BaseConsumable`.
3. Use `boost::any` and have `BaseConsumable` has a map to the attributes, and process the map using `IOnlyCareAboutCommunOp` as it know what to look for.

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseConsumable //I can't be a template and there are a lot of me
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseConsumable() = default;
};

class Consumable : public BaseConsumable
{
public:
    virtual ~Consumable() = default;
    virtual void IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds() const = 0;

protected:
    Consumable() = default;
};

class ConsumableTypeOne : public Consumable
{
public:
    ConsumableTypeOne() : Consumable() {};
    virtual void IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Im implemented" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void ImSomthingSpecialOne() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am special One" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ConsumableTypeTwo : public Consumable
{
public:
    ConsumableTypeTwo() : Consumable() {};
    virtual void IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Im implemented" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void ImSomthingSpecialTwo() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am special Two" << std::endl;
    }
};


class IOnlyConsumeBaseConsumable
{
public:
    void IOnlyCareAboutCommunOp(const std::shared_ptr<const BaseConsumable>& ImConsumableAndTheyAreLotsOfMe) const
    {
        //ImConsumableAndTheyAreLotsOfMe->IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds(); //How to do this without casting?
    };
};
```

Could you please help me if you have come accross this, or this is exactly why casting exists in the first place? (I do care about speed).

Comment: Advice -- You could have cut this down considerably if you used shorter names and maybe two derived classes.

Comment: I have just copied pasted my case so I don't miss anything, sorry if it's too long

Comment: Test the result of `dynamic_cast< Consumable *>(ImConsumableAndTheyAreLotsOfMe.get())`  unless you are 100% sure then just use `static_cast`.

Comment: I know it's safer but surely slower and surely run time. I do care about speed :)

Comment: you need to make sure it's a valid target anyway. doing it in any other form would probably not faster than simply `dynamic_cast` it.

Comment: I really was considering 3. using boost. I shouldn't use that?

Comment: _".. I do care about speed.."_ write the easiest to understand correct code you can.  Measure to see if it hits your performance requirements under realistic load.  If you need to, use a profiler to find the actual worst path.

Comment: Aren't you asking about the *Visitor* pattern?

Comment: Thanks sooo much, let me google it! Thank you! If this works that would be greaaaat!

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I don't see how visitor help here. OP need pretty specific behavior and dynamic cast to `Consumable` is way easier.

Comment: @Vero that said in your shown code it can be `static_cast`ed as there are no other possibility.

Comment: @Vero and for 3rd option, well I fail to see how it can be faster with that much of operations.

Comment: I agree the boost approach might be a bit hacky and not the C++ of doing things, because what I am doing is "exactly" what python does by sving attribues in a map with "boost::any". I am checking the visitor pattern and it looks smart but not sure I can apply it, still thinking

Comment: If you want to be able to call `ImConsumableAndTheyAreLotsOfMe->IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds();` without casting, then either declare `IamSomethingCommunBetweenChilds` as `virtual` in `BaseConsumable`, or else change `IOnlyCareAboutCommunOp()` to take in a `Consumable` instead of a `BaseConsumable`.

Comment: Thanks @Lebeau but I think you missed something the others took into account, of course this is the first thing that one think off and it is the goal of virtual function. You missed //I can't be a template and there are a lot of me. Lots of me means I can at each time I need a communOp I have to add it :) Thanks very much anyays!